# Php date keeps counting from 09:04:00 to 09:04:59

Tags: php, datetime

I have some trouble with php's date function.

Heres my code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Copenhagen");
echo date("Y/m/d h:m:s");
?>
```

What it outputs: 2014/04/07 09:04:31 Its keep counting from 04:00 to 04:59 and then it repeats again and again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date  the format codes are listed there, including what `m` stands for. You've used `m` twice in your format string, yet somehow expect PHP to know one should be (m)onths and the other should be (m)inutes?

Comment: I feel so stupid I didnt saw that i wrote m twice...

Comment: No worries. Everyone suffers on Mondays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m` is for months. `i` is for minutes:

```
echo date("Y/m/d h:m:s");
```

should be

```
echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s");
```

Comment: Ps. Do you know how to get it into a 24 hour format?? It should say 21:04:06 instead of 09:04:06 @John Conde

Comment: Change the lowercase `h` to an uppercase `H`. `H:i:s`.